# Rich many-to-many assosiation. Only allow one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

I need to limit my rich many-to-many association table to only one association per unique par. (rails).

That means i want terminals (model 1) and subscriptions (model 2) to have one custom_price (rich join) not any more than that.

How is this done most elegantly?

So far i have done:

```
  def new_custom_price
    @terminal_id = params[:terminal_id]
    @subscription_id = params[:subscription_id]

    @custom_price = CustomPrice.find_or_initialize_by_terminal_id_and_subscription_id( @terminal_id, @subscription_id)

    render action: 'custom_price'

  end

  def create_custom_price
    @terminal_id = params[:terminal_id]
    @subscription_id = params[:subscription_id]

    @custom_price = CustomPrice.new(custom_price_params.merge( :terminal_id => @terminal_id, :subscription_id => @subscription_id))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @custom_price.save
        format.js { render action: 'add_custom_price' }
      else
        format.js {  }
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: This wont be a many-to-many relationship if you can only have one relation in the join table. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Hmm i thought about that my self. the problem is that each Terminal can have many prices and subscriptions can have many prices. But each pari (terminal_id = 1 and subscription_id = 1) can only have one record. So could i use has_one custom_prices model in terminals/subscriptions?

Comment: By definition, each pair will have only one record in the join model. Why not make the join model the CustomPrice model, with belongs_to associations to both Terminal and Subscription. No need to do anything out of the ordinary here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things you can do to handle this: (This is assuming "price" is the unique part of the many to many relationships)

1) Validation in CustomPrice

```
validates :price, uniqueness: {scope: [:terminal_id, :subscription_id]}
```

- Unique Price on CustomPrice with a scope of Terminal and Subscription IDs
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

2) Use helpers

```
CustomPrice.find_or_create_by(custom_price_params.merge( :terminal_id => @terminal_id, :subscription_id => @subscription_id))
```

- Similar to the one used in your new action
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by